# Word Problem - Linear distance in terms of a walking velocity and a second driving velocity

Tags: word-problem

Every day I pick up my son from the bus stop at $4:00$ PM and go home. One day he started walking (towards home), leaving school at $3:30$ and I met him at some point in between. We arrived home $10$ minutes earlier then usual. How far did my son walk? This problem seems to be easily solved with algebra but intuitively it seems the son walks a third as fast as I drive making the $10$ minutes to $30$ minutes ratio $\frac{1}{3}$. That would mean it usually takes $15$  minutes to drive one way. Can anyone describe what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining your word problem, one thing goes through my mind:

> So many variables, so little time.

It might be the case that the solution is not unique!

OK, let us try to crank out any solution.

Suppose the distance of the school from home is 30 miles and the car velocity is given by

$\tag 1 v_c = \frac{1 \text{ mile}} {\text{min}}$

and you leave the home at 3:30 PM to pick up your son.

Before your son started leaving early, it took you 30 minutes to get to the school bus stop and 30 minutes to get home, so you got home at 4:30 PM, so a 60 minute round-trip.

Suppose now that your son starts walking to meet you, leaving also at 3:30 PM at a velocity of $v_s$. We are asked to calculate the distance $P$ where you meet your son from the school bus stop ($S = 0$) with the home at $H = 30$:

[image]

Now we know that time is distance divided by velocity, and the round-trip is now 50 minutes,

$\tag 2 \frac{H-P}{1} + \frac{P}{v_s} = 50$

and

$\tag 3 \frac{P}{v_s} = \frac{H-P}{1}$

So $2H - 2P = 50$. Since $H = 30$, $P = 5$.

---

There can be many solutions to this problem:

Suppose again the distance of the school is 30 miles but now you have a really fast car that travels at a velocity of $\frac{3 \text{ mile}} {\text{min}}$. In this case you leave the house a 3:50 PM and get home at 4:10 PM when your son doesn't walk. If your son walks a distance of 5 miles, he can cut down your round trip to 50 miles. To travel 50 miles takes your car

$\tag 4 \frac{50}{3} = 16.6666$

If you leave at 3:50 PM you both get home at around 4:07 PM, so your son's effort only saved you $ 3 \frac{1}{3}$ minutes, not 10 minutes. So the distance your son travels is not uniquely defined in this word problem.

If your son can save you 10 minutes, the variables are constrained and related in some way:

What if the bus stop is right at the front of your house? How long does it take to back your car out of the driveway?

Answer (score 3):

You must have picked him up at $3:55$ pm, $5$ minutes away from the bus stop at the speed you travel, thus saving $10$ minutes on the round trip. He was walking for $25$ minutes so your speed is $5$ times faster than his.

Example: Say on a normal day you leave home at $3:45$ pm, drive for $15$ minutes pick your son up at $4:00$ pm, drive for $15$ minutes back and arrive home at $4:15$pm

Next day, you leave home at $3:45$ pm, drive for only $10$ minutes where you meet you son walking and pick him up at $3:55$ pm, drive for $10$ minutes back and arrive home at $4:05$ pm, $10$ minutes earlier than usual.

Your son therefore was walking from $3:30$ pm to $3:55$ pm, for a time of $25$ minutes and walked a distance which you drive in only $5$ minutes (you only drove for $10$ minutes instead of $15$). Hence you travel $5$ times faster than your son walks.

We do not have enough information to determine anything else like the actual speeds or distances.

Say the distance $d_{hs}$from home to school is $5$ miles. A $15$ minute drive for you is done at $$v(mph) = \frac{d (\text{miles})}{t(\text{hrs})} = \frac{5}{(\frac{15}{60})} = 20\text{mph}$$

We worked out that your son walks at one fifth your speed which is $4\text{mph}$ so the distance he walks is determined from $d = vt$

$$d_{son} = 4\cdot \frac{25}{60} = \frac{100}{60} = \frac{5}{3}\text{miles}$$
We are dividing the time in minutes by $60$ to get the time in hours as our speed is in miles per hour.

Comment: i still dont get it . can u explain ?

Comment: See additional info added to my answer.

Comment: and i get it ! or at least looking back at your initial answer : You must have picked him up at 3:55 pm, 5 minutes away from the bus stop at the speed you travel, thus saving 10 minutes on the round trip. He was walking for 25 minutes so your speed is 5 times faster than his.---> the 10 minutes saved must be divided by 2 to get the

Comment: rountrip of what it was if he had not walked ..10 minutes TWO ways right?

Comment: The part about him leaving at 3:30 is not useless, from it you can figure he walked for 25 mins. 3:55 - 3:30 = 25 min. I think you've got it.

Comment: damn where do u teach at ? and if u dont teach , u should . u made things crystal clear in like the fewest words possible ( examples !) thanku

Comment: Thanks. Retired now, taught high school and then college after retiring early from aeronautical engineering.

Comment: u have a gift , thanks again ✌

Comment: maybe u thought my question stimulating enough to upvote ? 

Comment: so as for the question how far did he walk ..he walked 25 minutes and covered the same distance i traveled in the five minutes to get him .this means he made it to half way point right ? equal distances covered by him leaving at 330

Comment: Assuming the time for you to drive from home to school is $15$ minutes, and the distance $d$ unknown, your speed would be $4d$ mph and your son's speed would be $\frac{4d}{5}$ mph. He would therefore walk $\frac{4d}{5}(\frac{25}{60}) = \frac{d}{3}$ miles. That is $\frac{1}{3}$ the distance from school to home.

Comment: how do u get the 60 as the denominator?

Comment: i dont follow how you got 4d/5 either 

Comment: I added the calculation for speed and the distance your son walks assuming a distance of 5 miles from home to school in my answer above.

Comment: so without assuming u cannot find the distance he walks ? there is not enough information ??

Comment: Your double negative equates to assuming you can find the distance he walks, which you can say only if you know the speed of the walker, or the speed of the car, or the distance from home to school in my example above.

Comment: is the distance d the distance the son walks? from school to where he gets picked up ? that would be d/25 right?

Comment: distance is velocity times time. For the son, $d_{son} = 4\cdot \frac{25}{60}$

Comment: i c why it is d/ 25 for the speed of son because he travel for 25 minutes and of course i know speed is d/t . what im stuck on is where u got the 4 and the 60

Comment: and where do u get the 4d?!

Comment: i now see how u contrived the 4 and 60 . the 60 is to convert the 15 minutes to mph ! ( a duh moment of mine ) the 4 is because u assumed distance from home to school is 5 miles . but can u do that ??

Comment: phil i now get everything  from.the 4d ( this is from the 15/60 ) and also why it is then 1/5 of that ! .I added a bounty about an hour too soon lol as it became clear after i put the bounty on this question which in the end only made the problem more complicated  your solution was more succinct yet made me think more